# Finding sum of a series with e, unsure about simplification in last step.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm finding the sum of a series $\frac{(4e)^n}{12^{1-n}}$, and at the end of this example problem they have $\frac{4e}{1-\frac{e}{3}}$ then they simplify that to a find answer of $\frac{12e}{3-e}$.

My attempt was $\frac{4e}{\frac{2}{3}e}=4e*\frac{3}{2e}=\frac{12e}{2e}$. What are they doing to get to the answer they got?

Comment: Um.. $1 \neq e$ isn't what you mean, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{4e}{1-\frac{e}{3}}=\frac{4e}{\frac{3-e}{3}}=4e:\frac{3-e}{3}=4e \cdot \frac{3}{3-e} = \frac{12e}{3-e}$